# Why lottieRef returns only null?

Tags: reactjs, lottie

Using the library "@ lottiefiles/react-lottie-player"

You need to get lottieRef to interact with animation, but I get null.

Code reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-rgb-7dp4j0?file=/src/HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker.jsx

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import {Player} from "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player";

export default function App() {
  const player = useRef(null)
  const lottie = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(lottie && lottie.current){
      console.log(lottie.current) //return null
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Player
                lottieRef={data => lottie.current = data}
                ref={player}
                onEvent={event =>{
                  if(event === "load"){
                    lottie.current.play() //nothing
                  }
                }}
                keepLastFrame={true}
                autoplay={false}
                loop={true}
                src={"https://lottie.host/2c01fd6c-437d-494e-af27-2a37e322bc60/prXv4Ic6px.json"}
                style={{width: "100%", height: "2.5em", padding: "0", margin: "0"}}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

There is also an interesting point.
If you output lottie, we get an object with null (while there is something inside it)
And if you output lottie.current, we get null.
Reference to an example of this thing: https://ibb.co/RQWxLkJ

Comment: I tried this code, seems like the onEvent (load) is triggered before lottieRef is set.

Comment: I wrote to the discord community, if there is an answer, I will write here

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the lottie ref into your ref like the following (see ref on the div):

```
export default function App() {
   const player = useRef(null)
   const lottie = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(lottie && lottie.current){
      console.log(lottie.current) //return null
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Player
                lottieRef={data => lottie.current = data}
                ref={player}
                onEvent={event =>{
                  if(event === "load"){
                    lottie.current && lottie.current.play() //nothing
                  }
                }}
                keepLastFrame={true}
                autoplay={false}
                loop={true}
                src={"https://lottie.host/2c01fd6c-437d-494e-af27-2a37e322bc60/prXv4Ic6px.json"}
                style={{width: "100%", height: "2.5em", padding: "0", margin: "0"}}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way I am able to get the animation object when I console `lottie.current`
[image]

Comment: I apologize that I previously did not save the code to the codesandbox.io. Now I have made a little more a semblance of my project and again met with this mistake.

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-rgb-7dp4j0?file=/src/HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker.jsx

Comment: I noticed that if you use view switching, then:
In project view - animation does not work and lottie.current return null
And in the current module view everything works great

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use useState to save the animationData rather than a ref. But there was also an issue on the player where the 'load' event was firing but the player hadn't finish setting its internal instance of the animation therefor calling play() wouldn't work. This was happening only on functional components in React that's why it went undiscovered.

I've made a few changes to your code and to the player, using v1.5.2 you should be able to accomplish what you're looking for:

```js
import css from "./HorizontalPicker.module.css";
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Player } from "@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player";

const HorizontalPicker = () => {
  const player = useRef(null);
  // const lottie = useRef(null);
  const [lottie, setLottie] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (lottie) {
      console.log(" Lottie animation data : ");
      console.log(lottie);

      // You can also play by calling the underlying lottie method
      // lottie.play();
    }
  }, [lottie]);

  return (
    <>
      <Player
        onEvent={(event) => {
          // console.log(event);
          if (event === "instanceSaved" && player && player.current) {
            console.log("Playing animation..");
            player.current.play();
          }
        }}
        lottieRef={(data) => {
          setLottie(data);
        }}
        ref={player}
        keepLastFrame={true}
        autoplay={false}
        loop={true}
        src={
          "https://lottie.host/2c01fd6c-437d-494e-af27-2a37e322bc60/prXv4Ic6px.json"
        }
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default HorizontalPicker;
```

Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lottie-react-functional-component-2bs8fs?file=/src/HorizontalPicker/HorizontalPicker.jsx

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to official documentation https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-react, lottieRef represents a callback function which is fired by Player component (and this function returns AnimationFrame object)

I'm not familiar with this library, and whatever I'll describe next are just my assumptions :) Seems that whenever player "plays", it displays frames one-by-one (from json file in "src" attribute"). And whenever player displays frames from .json file - Player fires "lottieRef" event which you utilize to set lottie.current. And player starts displaying frames only when it loads .json data using "src" parameter in Player definition (see network tab in your browser to ensure that additional http request presents)

And in this case everything seems pretty logical: you try to access "lottie" variable in useEffect of your component but it's empty as far as Player did not manage to display any frame yet because the callback (lottieRef) did not fire yet as far as .json file is not loaded yet. No matter if .json file is large or small, Player requests it via additional http call, which requires some (even minital) amount time. And useEffect fires before .json is loaded immediately after rendering DOM (that's how ReactJS works)

On the other hand, if you delay a bit request to "lottie" ref - you'll see that it is populated:
[image]

Code example:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { Player } from '@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player';

export default function App() {
    const player = useRef(null);
    const lottie = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => console.log(lottie), 50);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Player
                lottieRef={(data) => (lottie.current = data)}
                ref={player}
                keepLastFrame={true}
                autoplay={false}
                loop={true}
                src={
                    'https://lottie.host/2c01fd6c-437d-494e-af27-2a37e322bc60/prXv4Ic6px.json'
                }
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

So if you delay onEvent callback event a bit, "lottie" ref would be initialized by that moment and .play() would work:

```
onEvent={(event) => {
    event === 'load' &&
        setTimeout(
            () => lottie.current && lottie.current.play()
        );
    }
}
```

BUT, if the only purpose you have is to execute Player whenever it's ready - why not to use "autoplay" built-in property ? (autoplay={true})

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

import { Player } from '@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player';

export default function App() {
    const player = useRef(null);
    const lottie = useRef(null);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Player
                lottieRef={(data) => (lottie.current = data)}
                ref={player}
                keepLastFrame={true}
                autoplay={true}
                loop={true}
                src={
                    'https://lottie.host/2c01fd6c-437d-494e-af27-2a37e322bc60/prXv4Ic6px.json'
                }
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Hope it'll help